# Usando executor no android

Tags: java, android

Estou tentando utilizar um executor para gravar dados no banco usando threads. Ao instanciar um objeto da classe Executor Service e recuperar uma instancia de de Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(); me retorna o erro que não esta encontrando o instancia/declaração de newSingleThreadExecutor.

```
   ExecutorService exec = new Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

                       exec.execute(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                //Adicionando tarefa
                                addTask(itemList);

                            }
                        });
```

Comment: Você adicionou o respectivo import? `import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService `

Comment: sim -> import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors; -> somente o newSingleThreadExecutor() nao esta reconhecendo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não use o `new`.

`Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` é um método e não uma classe.

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

A sua função é criar uma instância de ExecutorService que, neste caso, usa um único *worker thread*.

Comment: Muito Obrigado.